# USB to VGA adapter

Tags: ubuntu, usb, монитор

Задался я целью подключить к ноутбуку второй внешний монитор. Много решений находил средней геморроистости, потом набрёл на е-бее на такую штуку: http://www.ebay.com/itm/1080P-USB-3-0-to-VGA-Display-External-Video-Graphics-Adapter-Cable-For-Win-7-ED-/122196805966?hash=item1c737f494e:g:-FAAAOSwB09YP~vk
Хочу заказать, уже вот прям очень хочу, ибо эта приблуда способна решить все мои проблемы. Но вот такой вопрос - Ubuntu с ним подружится? Ибо нужен не дублирующий/зеркальный какой-то монитор, а вполне полноценный, чтобы можно было расширить на него рабочий стол, таскать туда-сюда окошки и т.д.
Может, сталкивался кто-то, или опыт имел? Заодно интересно было бы узнать кто как подобные задачи реализовывал.

Comment: это видео-адаптер. его название не приводится, а в одном и том же ноунейме может быть впаяно всё что угодно. т.е. сказать, будет ли **конкретный присланный вам** экземпляр корректно работать, сможете определить только вы лично, после получения посылки.

Answer (score 0):

https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/Reliable-Compatible-With-USB2-0-1PC-USB-3-0-to-VGA-Video-Display-External-Cable-Adapter/32713770890.html

Вот такую штуку нашёл на АлиЭкспресс, там чётко написано что она поддерживает расширение рабочего стола. Если кому надо, you welcome.